# Inside a gridview (label turn to textbox on click) One at a time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Following this Question/Answer regarding changing label to textbox inside a gridview gives me a answer on my project
[Changing label to textbox on javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170221/changing-label-to-textbox-on-javascript)
but there is a slight modification cause on my project I want that only one click at a time be used. Cause on what the question ask it only show how to change label to gridview without on change one at a time.

Ive tried googling it but I cant find the right answer. 
Any Ideas? My codes is same as the question above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the pseudo-code on how I implemented it,

```
$('label#elementYouWantThemToClick').click(function(){
    var textbox_HTML = '<textbox></textbox>'
    $(this).parent().html(textbox_HTML) // This will destroy the event listener on your label as well
});
```

Comment: is that jquery? how can I use that sir?

Comment: Yes, m'am. If you look into Jquery (www.jquery.com) it's easy to get running and gives you a few more handles on javascript to speed up dev. There's plenty of tutes on how to get it running for you.